# Call channel connect function from another js file

Tags: jquery, function, sockets, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have following folder structure in phoenix:

```
web/
  static/
    js/
      app.js
      script.js
      socket.js
```

---

`app.js` has...

```
import socket from "./socket"

import script from "./script"
```

---

`brunch-config.js` has...

```
files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

`script.js` has...

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function() {
    connectToChannel(data);
});
```

---

`socket.js` has...

```
import {Socket} from "phoenix"

let socket = new Socket("ws://example.com/updates", {params: {"auth-token": "AUTH-TOKEN"}})

function connectToChannel(data) {
    socket.connect()

    let channel = socket.channel("updates:new", {})
    channel.join()
      .receive("ok", resp => { console.log("Joined successfully", resp) })
      .receive("error", resp => { console.log("Unable to join", resp) })

    channel.on("update", payload => {
        console.log(payload);
    })
}

export default socket
```

...yet when I click `some-button` I get the following error in the browser's console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: connectToChannel is not defined

Connection is successful if I take the contents of `socket.js` and put it inside `script.js`, but I would like to keep them separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connectToChannel` function is local to the file it's defined in. Neither `api.js`, nor `script.js` can see it.

What you can do is export it from `socket.js` and pass it to `app.js`, something like this:

```
// socket.js

import {Socket} from "phoenix"

let socket = new Socket("ws://example.com/updates", {params: {"auth-token": "AUTH-TOKEN"}})

function connectToChannel(data) {
    socket.connect()

    let channel = socket.channel("updates:new", {})
    channel.join()
      .receive("ok", resp => { console.log("Joined successfully", resp) })
      .receive("error", resp => { console.log("Unable to join", resp) })

    channel.on("update", payload => {
        console.log(payload);
    })
}
// export the function too
export {socket, connectToChannel}


// app.js
import {socket, connectToChannel} from "./socket"

import script from "./script"

// pass the fn explicitly
script(connectToChannel);
```

And finally wrap `script.js` in a function that receives `connectToChannel`:

```
export default function(connectToChannel) {
  $('#some-button').on('click', function() {
    connectToChannel(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _script2.default) is not a function` on the line in `app.js` where it says `script(connectToChannel);` and `Uncaught TypeError: connectToChannel is not a function` on the line I'm calling that function.

Comment: Did you *export default* that function from `script.js`? Did you export `export {socket, connectToChannel}` from `socket.js`? You probably missed something, because that should be working.

I just pasted these three files into an empty brunch app and it *is* working.

Comment: sorry, where did you say in your answer I had to *export default* that (which?) function?

Comment: I start to think I'm probably missing where and how `script(connectToChannel);` is supposed to be used... do I just add it into `app.js` after I did the imports? it's not very clear, as you added code into the same block while some of them are supposed to be on different files...

Comment: Yep, it's supposed to go into `app.js`. I couldn't get the block to split, but I have added a comment in the block where `app.js` starts.

The last paragraph on the answer also says to make `script.js` export a function which receives `connectToChannel`. This is one way to get it there. Another could be to leave script.js mostly as is, but add an `import {connectToChannel} from "./socket"` to the top

Comment: ok, I could make it work following your advice, thanks so much for your help!